# ftp function get stuck won't continue after finally?

Tags: java, exception, ftp

I have a FTP function in java - that work OK .
my problem is when there is an exception - it won't finish ,
just show me the exception and get stuck 
why?

```
public static void UploadFTP ()
    {
        String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s";
        String host = "10.0.0.1";
        String user = "FTP";
        String pass = "FTP";
        String filePath="/home/pi/SendData.log";
        String uploadPath = "/car.txt";

        ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl,user,pass,host,uploadPath);
        System.out.println("Upload URL:  " + ftpUrl);
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream
                (filePath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte [4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("File Upload Finish!");
        }

        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally 
        {}

    }
```

I need it to show me the problem and return to the main code 
so what is wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: A) follow java naming conventions, method names go camelCase. B) your method looks fine, when there is an exception, that will be printed, and the method returns (as there is no other code here). So: the problem isn't in this method, it is in the way how your other code is using the method.

Comment: sorry - but what do you mean? can you explain?

Comment: I mean: your method looks fine. We can't help you unless you provide more context. The method you are showing prints the exception trace, and then returns. That is all that we know at this point. If you want us to help, you have to provide **all** information that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: What did you do to debug the problem? How did you determine that an execution "stuck" in this function? Show us [mcve] that can be used to reproduce and debug the problem.

Comment: I'm using raspberry with java , that upload a FTP file once every 10 seconds.       I don't know how to minimal - so I will ask :       in "main"  I'm calling UploadF0TP() , if I will put this in try+catch - can it solve the problem?